# Animate / EaselJS - removeEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

I have an issue w/ Adobe Animate CC, and the Javascript framework it uses, EaselJS/CreateJS.  I can add event listeners w/o issue, but I cannot remove them.  I have tried various things from the debugger, including stepping into their JS removeEventListener handler - Although the two variables look identical, they are never == (or ===) so the even listener isn't removed.

Here is the code I use, and it's purpose it to fade-in an element when hovering over it:

```
this.fadeIn = function(target_mc)
    {
        target_mc.alpha = 0;
        target_mc.visible = true;

        target_mc.removeEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);
        target_mc.addEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame.bind(this));

        function fadeIn_onEnterFrame(evt)
        {
            evt.currentTarget.alpha = evt.currentTarget.alpha + .2;
            if (evt.currentTarget.alpha >= 1)
            {
                evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);
            } // end if
        }
    } // End of the function
```

So you know, it is added to the Canvas in frame_0, and is called from a "mouseover" listener added to each clothing type (it's for a drag-and-drop dress-up game, FWIW)

```
function clothing_onRollOver()
{
    this.hint_mc.desc_mc.desc1_txt.text = this.articleName;
    this.fadeIn(this.hint_mc);
    this.clothingOver = true;
};
clothing.addEventListener("mouseover",clothing_onRollOver.bind(this));
```

Comment: Is the error on `target_mc.removeEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);` or ... `evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);` or both?

Comment: I'd go with "both" - neither appears to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some scoping issue with your code. The snippet below fixes your issue and correctly removes the event listener, however I have no idea why your current implementation was not working correctly.

The difference is that I have removed the bind from `target_mc.addEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame.bind(this));`

However I am unsure as to why `.bind()` was causing this issue.

```
stage.enableMouseOver();

clothingOver = false;

this.hint_mc.visible = false;

this.fadeIn = function(target_mc)
{
    console.log(target_mc);

    target_mc.alpha = 0;
    target_mc.visible = true;

    target_mc.removeEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);
    target_mc.addEventListener("tick",fadeIn_onEnterFrame);

    function fadeIn_onEnterFrame(evt)
    {
        console.log("tick");
        evt.currentTarget.alpha = evt.currentTarget.alpha + .2;

        if (evt.currentTarget.alpha >= 1)
        {
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener("tick", fadeIn_onEnterFrame);
        } // end if
    }
} // End of the function



function clothing_onRollOver()
{
    //this.hint_mc.desc_mc.desc1_txt.text = this.articleName;
    this.fadeIn(this.hint_mc);
    this.clothingOver = true;
};


this.clothing.addEventListener("mouseover",clothing_onRollOver.bind(this));
```

Sorry that I am not able to identify the exact root cause for you.

Comment: Actually, you ID'd it - I took the ".bind(this)" off of the addEventListener, and it was able to properly remove it.  I should note, I also tried adding ".bind(this)" to all of the add/remove calls, and that did NOT work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason this works is because `bind` creates a new function each time. If you save off the value of `bind`, you can remove it later: `this.fn = fadeIn_onEnterFrame.bind(); btn.addEventListenen("tick", fn); btn.removeEventListener("tick", fn);` Binding is good if you want to maintain the `this` scope.

Comment: Thanks @Lanny - I did a cursory search for an explanation after implementing Zze's changes, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @HungryBeagle I was searching as well for the reason as to why `.bind();` would cause this to happen - that is what I meant by not being able to identify the root cause :) - glad to help though.